# How do you tell if an option was specified when using System.CommandLine?

Tags: c#, command-line-arguments, system.commandline

With a root command:

```
new RootCommand
{
    new Option<string>("--myoption")
};
```

how do you tell the difference between

```
./myapp
```

and

```
./myapp --myoption ""
```

?

I initially assumed that the option would be null if it wasn't specified, but it's not, it's an empty string :( Adding an explicit default of `null` also doesn't work; this code still prints out `""` when no options are passed in:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var rootCommand = new RootCommand
    {
        new Option<string>("--myoption", () => null)
    };
    rootCommand.Handler = CommandHandler.Create<string>(Run);
    rootCommand.Invoke(args);
}

private static void Run(string myoption)
{
    Console.WriteLine(myoption == null ? "(null)" : '"' + myoption + '"');
}
```

If the default is set to a non-null string, the default does come through as expected; only `null` is mysteriously changed into an empty string.

Answer (score 3):

You can describe a function to calculate a default value. If using C# 8 or newer, you may need to explicitly say that your string is nullable by adding the question mark at the end.

```cs
new RootCommand
{
    new Option<string?>("--myoption", () => null, "My option. Defaults to null");
};
```

I would have thought that this would work, but I was able to set up a working example on dotnetfiddle here https://dotnetfiddle.net/uxyC8Y which shows even with every parameter marked as nullable, it is still being returned as an empty string. This may be an issue with the System.CommandLine project, so I put in an issue here https://github.com/dotnet/command-line-api/issues/1459

EDIT: This issue was resolved just 2 days ago with this commit https://github.com/dotnet/command-line-api/pull/1458/files it will take some time before this fix shows up in a published NuGet package, but it will be fixed eventually in future versions of the library.

Without being able to use nulls, my only suggestion would be to use a very distinct default string to mark a value as not assigned.

```cs
const string defaultString = "Not Assigned.";
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var rootCommand = new RootCommand
    {
        new Option<string>("--myoption", () => defaultString)
    };
    rootCommand.Handler = CommandHandler.Create<string>(Run);
    rootCommand.Invoke(args);
}

private static void Run(string myoption)
{
    Console.WriteLine(myoption == defaultString ? "(null)" : '"' + myoption + '"');
}
```

Comment: I tried that; unfortunately with an explicit default of `null`, it still actually default to an empty string! If I have an explicit default of anything apart from `null`, then that works, but `null` does not. I will update the question.

Comment: @MarkRaymond are you using C# 8 with nullable references https://endjin.com/blog/2020/10/dotnet-csharp-8-nullable-references-empty-strings ? I think by default C# 8 will not allow null values, unless you explicitly say that nulls are allowed. I'll update my answer with what should fix it.